# My table contain tdate column, datatype date

Tags: sql, oracle

Here my table contain tdate column with date as datatype. Suppose I am deleting data by using where condition , my min(tdate)--21-02-19 and max(tdate)--25-02-19:-  where

```
tdate between TO_DATE('2019-02-21 00:00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('2019-02-21 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Here I am deleting my 21-02-19 data after that I committed my txn
Here I'm selecting min(tdate)  then it showing tdate 21-02-19 instead of showing 22-02-19 (which is I'm not expecting)
And after above delete command,  if I'm deleting using this where condition tdate='21-02-19';
Commit
Then some txn deleted, and then showing min(tdate)=22-02-19 which is I'm expecting

Please provide solution to this type of problem
I think data is inserted different form of tdate

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? `TO_DATE` is not a T-SQL Function. That looks like Oracle to me.

Comment: Yes it is Oracle question

Comment: Then why have you tagged SQL Server and SQL Server 2012 and not Oracle?

Comment: *"Then why have you tagged SQL Server and SQL Server 2012 and not Oracle? "* @Larnu well Oracle database is a capable *"SQL Server"* it you don't read that the tags mean here on Stackoverflow it is very easy to mistag.. Topicstarter little hint: next time hold the mouse on the tag to know what the tag is about but prevent mis tagging in the future..

Comment: I can understand SQL Server, on it's own @RaymondNijland (and many of us that use SQL Server are used to having to remove the tag when users tag it erroneously when not reading the text that tells them not to tag it), it was the addition of SQL Server 2012, and the omission of Oracle that really confused me.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm not sure that *"a SQL server"* is a thing. On the other hand, I suppose it's nice to see "SQL Server" being used to refer to Oracle for a change, rather than "SQL" referring to some Microsoft product.

Comment: So, you want to delete all the data for the date `21-02-19` ? Why don't you say it clearly rather than beating around the bush?  If that's what you want, avoid using `between` and `time` components in your query. This is better : `where tdate >= DATE '2019-02-21' AND tdate < DATE '2019-02-22'`

Comment: *"I'm not sure that "a SQL server" is a thing."* @WilliamRobertson well why not you also have a "Game Server" to indicate a server which is running a game the "SQL Server" term can be used to also indicate  a server which is running SQL then right? .. i agree you will get misunderstandings between using a "SQL Server" term instead of using "database server" because of the existing Microsft product.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `trunc` function as

```
delete tab where trunc(tdate) = date'2019-02-21'
```

btw, in your where condition the time point `'2019-02-21 00:00:00'` is missing for that day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the root of your problem:

```
tdate between TO_DATE('2019-02-21 00:00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and ...
-----------------------------------------^
```

Your date range starts at one second past midnight. Consequently your DELETE statement will not hit any records created at exactly midnight or which had a date with no explicit time element such as `trunc(sysdate)`.

Datetime can be a pain in the neck. BETWEEN makes it worse because it executes *less than or equal to* with its upper bound. The cleanest way to define these ranges is with explicit tests for each bound, using *greater than or equal to* and *less than* respectively:

```
where tdate >= date '2019-02-21'
and tdate < date '2019-02-22'
```